# Current methods to play static video files on web pages?

Tags: html

As I'm a bit out of tune with web programming I tried to look up what is currently being used in order to display static video files on a web page.

After google showed me either the video tag for PC or some programs for android,... I'm wondering what are really now the current methods to display such videos? Is it JUST the video tag nowadays? Or are there also other methods that are "modern"?

Comment: "some programs for android" - How are you going to embed those in your page? Of course a phone or tablet may have an app to play video, but targeting that specifically would not count as good ol' platform-agnostic web development.

Comment: youtube? :S No idea what you mean

Comment: @GolezTrol that was my thought there. I wondered if that is really the normal way or if there are others.

Answer (score 0):

The latest versions of the most popular browsers already support the `video` tag, so it should be as modern as you expect. The problem here is rather the video **format**. Each browser supports different formats for different types of operating systems, so this is one thing you should pay attention for. This [website](http://www.encoding.com/html5/) should give you a quick view of the current situation.

One more thing I can point you to is the support for older browsers. You should check if user's browser support the `video` tag and your video's encoding. In case it doesn't -- simply add a fallback to some older technology, such as flash or something else.